# How to check if the number is from same group or not

Tags: python, arrays, list

List Group Mapper:

```
a = [[658,659,660],[1217,1218,1219],[1691,1692,1693],[1694,1695,1696]]
```

should return true only if the the input array is from same group(nested list). if the input arry is from different group it should return false.

```
input1 = [658] --> True
input2 = [658,659] --> True
input3 = [658,659,660] --> True
input4 = [1217] --> True
input5 = [1217,1218] --> True
input6 = [1217,1218,1219] --> True
input7 = [1217,658] --> False
input8 = [1217,1218,658] --> False
input9 = [658,659,1217] --> False
```

Comment: So you're asking how to check if a list of numbers is contained entirely within a single list from another list of lists? What have you tried yourself? Please share what code you came up with and explain where or how you're stuck.

Comment: So you're asking how to check if a list of numbers is contained entirely within a single list from another list of lists? --> yes @Grismar

Comment: OK, what have you tried yourself? The problem can be solved in many ways - in as little as a single short line, or in a couple, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: haven't tried yet. any possible solution?

Comment: Your sample indicates that the values in subgroups are successive values. I'm not sure its a general law. ?  In the same way, all subgroups have 3 elements. I'm not sure it's a general law ? Either précise rules, either give a sample with all expected cases.

Comment: doesnt matter if it is a successive values or not. and also all subgroup have only 3 elements. but input can have 1 or 2 or 3 elements @pirela

Answer (score 3):

Define a function, where `a` is your list of groups and `i` is the input:

```
def check_input(a, i):
    for g in a:
        if all(x in g for x in i):
            return True
    return False
```

Example:

```
a = [[658,659,660],[1217,1218,1219],[1691,1692,1693],[1694,1695,1696]]

input1 = [658]
input2 = [658,659]
input3 = [658,659,660]
input4 = [1217]
input5 = [1217,1218]
input6 = [1217,1218,1219]
input7 = [1217,658]
input8 = [1217,1218,658]
input9 = [658,659,1217]

inputs = [input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7, input8, input9]
for i in inputs:
    print(check_input(a, i))
```

Returns:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

Caution handing over an empty list (`i=[]`) will result in `True`.

Comment: I would not call them cryptic, but yes if you prefer that...

Answer (score 2):

Try this (`inp` is your input list, `groups` your list group mapper):

```
def check_inp(inp, groups):
    if len(inp) == 0:
        return True
    g = next((group for group in groups if inp[0] in group), [])
    return all(x in g for x in inp)
```

Examples:

```
>>> groups = [[658,659,660],[1217,1218,1219],[1691,1692,1693],[1694,1695,1696]]
>>> check_inp([658], groups)
True
>>> check_inp([658, 659], groups)
True
>>> check_inp([658, 659, 660], groups)
True
>>> check_inp([1217], groups)
True
>>> check_inp([1217, 1218], groups)
True
>>> check_inp([1217, 1218, 1219], groups)
True
>>> check_inp([1217, 658], groups)
False
>>> check_inp([1217, 1218, 658], groups)
False
>>> check_inp([658, 659, 1217], groups)
False
```

Some special cases (input not in groups, and empty input):

```
>>> check_inp([1], groups)
False
>>> check_inp([], groups)
True
```

Comment: Or `return any(all(x in g for x in inp) for g in groups)`

Comment: This is working perfectly, thanks. but is there any simple function just like this?

Comment: `def check_input(a, i):
    return any(all(x in g for x in i) for g in a)` is really elegant props to @Grismar

Answer (score 1):

A readable way would be to change inputs to sets and look for subset

```py
def check(list_of_list, a_list):
    gen_of_set = (set(l) for l in list_of_list)
    a_set = set(a_list)
    
    for l in gen_of_set:
        if a_set.issubset(l):
            return True
    return False
```

Tests:

```py
a = [[658,659,660],[1217,1218,1219],[1691,1692,1693],[1694,1695,1696]]
test_1 = [658,659,1217]
test_2 = [658,659]

check(a, test_1) # False
check(a, test_2) # True
check([], test_1) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

I asks me if an old way of programming would be a way and if it would be less or more efficient against previous algorithms.
So, i wrote the following and then compare it with previous *chek_input* (the more elegant) and with check_inp.

```
groups = [[658,659,660],[1217,1218,1219],[1691,1692,1693],[1694,1695,1696]]
questions = [[658],[658,659],[658,659,660],[1217], [1217,1218],[1217,1218,1219],[1217,658],[1217,1218,658],[658,659,1217]]


def check_oldGeek (groups,question ):
expected = len(question)
for group in groups:
    count=0
    for elt in question:
        for value in group: 
            if (elt==value): #elt found in group break to next elt 
                count+=1
                break
        if (count == expected): # all elt found in the group
             return True
return(False)
```

After checking that all gave the same results, i mask the print to iterate on large numbers of trials without output time. Here are the results :

```
    --------- round : 10
check_oldGeek --- 5.412101745605469e-05 seconds 
check_input   --- 5.91278076171875e-05 seconds 
check_inp     --- 5.4836273193359375e-05 seconds 
--------- round : 100
check_oldGeek --- 0.0005178451538085938 seconds 
check_input   --- 0.0005512237548828125 seconds 
check_inp     --- 0.0005300045013427734 seconds 
--------- round : 1000
check_oldGeek --- 0.005194902420043945 seconds 
check_input   --- 0.005603790283203125 seconds 
check_inp     --- 0.005519866943359375 seconds 
--------- round : 10000
check_oldGeek --- 0.05125117301940918 seconds 
check_input   --- 0.05428814888000488 seconds 
check_inp     --- 0.05108284950256348 seconds 
--------- round : 100000
check_oldGeek --- 0.4925360679626465 seconds 
check_input   --- 0.5323500633239746 seconds 
check_inp     --- 0.5027801990509033 seconds 
--------- round : 1000000
check_oldGeek --- 4.900893926620483 seconds 
check_input   --- 5.328909873962402 seconds 
check_inp     --- 5.0314040184021 seconds
```

Conclusions :
The old geek gains (a little) in terms of response time :).
For my own, i appreciate the very synthetic *check_input*   but for beginners, my old programming way could be the most understandable.

Hope you enjoy these samples as i do .